# symfony : php does not seem to be available under /usr/bin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem in symfony 5.0.4, and I'm using ubuntu.

Whene I try to create the database with the commande line :

```
sudo symfony console doctrine:database:create
```

It shows this error :

-> php does not seem to be available under /usr/bin

and whene I run the commande line

```
symfony local:php:list
```

I shows :
 [image]

I tryed te execute this commande line :

```
 symfony local:php:refresh
```

But nothing changed.

My .env file :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:ahmed@127.0.0.1:3306/db_pinte?serverVersion=5.7
```

Some one have any idea for this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **php bin/console doctrine:database:create** instead of symfony

Comment: it give `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost` even if I use it with sudo

Comment: It's normal you should set up your database connexion in your .env file https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Comment: What are you using ? mysql ? pgsql ? and can you show me your DATABASE_URL ?

Comment: Yeah MySQL, I add DATABASE_URL in the question post

Comment: Is your user ahmed or root ? i think you switched your login and password ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207384/discussion-between-youssef-saoubou-and-d-ahmed).

Comment: the username is root, and the password is ahmed. like this : `mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name`, right ?